# MySQL not starting after migrating to a new Mac

Tags: mysql

I've done this in the past already without issues. But now... I bought a new MacBook Pro (M1 Pro Chip) and migrated everything from my Mac mini (M1 chip). When I start MAMP (Apache & mysql57), I get the following log:

```
2022-03-01T08:35:38.277831Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Trying to access page number 606273606 in space 0, space name innodb_system, which is outside the tablespace bounds. Byte offset 0, len 16384, i/o type read. If you get this error at mysqld startup, please check that your my.cnf matches the ibdata files that you have in the MySQL server.
2022-03-01T08:35:38.277843Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Server exits.
```

I already did a ton of research before asking here.
E.g. I found to delete all log files from `/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql57/ib_log*` but this generates the following log:

```
2022-03-01T08:41:24.352824Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html for information about forcing recovery.
2022-03-01T08:41:24.352966Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=0, page number=317] log sequence number 1648136393 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1648136222.
2022-03-01T08:41:24.352976Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html for information about forcing recovery.
2022-03-01T08:41:24.352999Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=0, page number=50] log sequence number 1648136734 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1648136222.
2022-03-01T08:41:24.353005Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html for information about forcing recovery.
...
...
2022-03-01T08:41:24.356856Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Trying to access page number 606273606 in space 0, space name innodb_system, which is outside the tablespace bounds. Byte offset 0, len 16384, i/o type read. If you get this error at mysqld startup, please check that your my.cnf matches the ibdata files that you have in the MySQL server.
2022-03-01T08:41:24.356861Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Server exits.
2022-03-01T08:41:24.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
```

I added a `my.conf` file with

```
[mysqld]
innodb_force_recovery = 1
```

at

- /Applications/MAMP/Library
- /Applicaiton/MAMP/conf
- /Application/MAMP/tmp/mysql

but this doesn't seem to do anything at all. At least I can't find anything in the logs.

What can I do to fix this issue?